# Proper way of saving Fragment transaction before exiting

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have my method for replacing `Fragment`s in my mainActivity..like this after clicking my `Button`...

```
FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment2 f2=new Fragment2();
    trans.replace(R.id.root_frame, f2,"Fragment2");
    trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    trans.commit();
    getPager().setCurrentItem(0);
```

and i need to save this change before exiting my app..so when i re-open my app transaction changes would be there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save your fragment state in shared preferences and retrieve it when the fragment gets recreated.

Save your state when you set the transaction

```
SharedPreferences  mypreferences=getActivity().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

 Editor editor= mypreferences.edit();
 editor.putString("transition","FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN");
   //do the same for other fragment states

 editor.commit();
```

Retreive your state in your onCreate() method.

```
String transition= mypreferences.getString("transition", "");
if(!transition.equals(""){
   transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
   //do the same for other fragment states
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot....you saved my day... (: one more question because i can't try this right now...do i have to call again transaction.replace () in onCreate () or fragments will be already replaced after re-opening...i'm still learning

Comment: Yes you still have to call the replace method in all cases in your onCreate(). Happy coding :)